# how to sort and group an array with symbolics in it?

Tags: python, sympy

```py
import sympy as smp
x,y,c,a = smp.symbols('x y c a', real=True)
arr= [5*y, 7*y, 2*y,13*y, 7*y, 2*y]
```

I want to sort and group this array in a way that the result is:

```py
[[2*y,2*y],[5*y],[7*y,7*y],[13*y]]
```

Is there any specific way that will help me first sort than group the similar element of an array that contain a specific symbol in it?

Comment: Hi. What is `smp`? Is it `import sympy as smp`?

Comment: Assuming this is sympy: Ironically, grouping is very easy, but sorting is a little bit awkward, because sympy doesn't a priori know that `5*y < 7*y`

Comment: do you know any way to sort this array?

Comment: `[list(g) for _,g in itertools.groupby(sorted(arr, key=lambda e:e.subs({y:1})))]`

Answer (score 2):

### TL;DR

```py
from itertools import groupby

[list(g) for _,g in groupby(sorted(arr, key=lambda e:e.subs({y:1})))]
# [[2*y, 2*y], [5*y], [7*y, 7*y], [13*y]]
```

### Explanations

- Grouping is always easy in python, and can be performed either with a `dict` of lists or with `sorted + itertools.groupby`;
- Sorting a list of `sympy` expressions is going to be a bit arbitrary, because `sympy` a priori doesn't know what is bigger between `5*y` and `7*y`.

##### Grouping with a `dict` of `lists`

```py
d = {}
for e in arr:
    d.setdefault(e, []).append(e)

print(d)
# {5*y: [5*y], 7*y: [7*y, 7*y], 2*y: [2*y, 2*y], 13*y: [13*y]}
```

##### Grouping with `itertools.groupby`

`groupby` will only group adjacent values, so in your case you need to sort the list **before** calling `groupby`.

Presuming `arr` is already sorted, you can get a list of groups this way:

```py
arr = [2*y, 2*y, 5*y, 7*y, 7*y, 13*y]
groups = [list(g) for _,g in groupby(arr)]
print(groups)
# [[2*y, 2*y], [5*y], [7*y, 7*y], [13*y]]
```

But if `arr` is not sorted, only adjacent groups will be recognised:

```py
arr = [5*y, 7*y, 2*y, 2*y, 13*y, 7*y]
groups = [list(g) for _,g in groupby(arr)]
print(groups)
# [[5*y], [7*y], [2*y, 2*y], [13*y], [7*y]]
```

##### Sorting

In python you can sort a sequence with `sorted`. However, this requires `<` to work between the elements in your sequence. Here, sympy a priori doesn't know how to compare expressions:

```py
print(5*y < 7*y)
# 5*y < 7*y     # not helpful

print(bool(5*y < 7*y))
# TypeError: cannot determine truth value of Relational

print(sorted(arr))
# TypeError: cannot determine truth value of Relational
```

So, we need to provide `sorted` with a `key` to tell it how to compare our sympy expressions. There are a lot of different possible ideas for that.

I think the simplest we can do here, is to ask `sympy` to evaluate the expression when `y = 1`:

```py
sorted(arr, key=lambda e:e.subs({y:1}))
# [2*y, 2*y, 5*y, 7*y, 7*y, 13*y]
```

Another possible idea would have been to extract the components of the expressions, using `.args`:

```py
print((5*y).args)
# (5, y)

from operator import attrgetter
print( sorted(arr, key=attrgetter('args')) )
# [2*y, 2*y, 5*y, 7*y, 7*y, 13*y]
```

However, the `.args` approach doesn't generalise very well if your expressions can be more complex than just `constant * y`. So I have a strong preference for the `.subs({y:1})` approach. If you get more complicated expressions, for instance `5*y**2+3*y+2`, then you can use `.subs(y=100)` instead for instance, so that the coefficient of `y**2` gets a stronger weight than the coefficient of `y`, which gets a stronger weight than the constant coefficient.

##### Conclusion

We can sort, then groupby:

```py
groups = [list(g) for _,g in groupby(sorted(arr, key=lambda e:e.subs({y:1})))]

print(groups)
# [[2*y, 2*y], [5*y], [7*y, 7*y], [13*y]]
```